# Preventation to HTTP Response Splitting attack

Tags: security, owasp

The OWASP page https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting mentions **this issue has been fixed in virtually all modern Java EE application servers** What does it means? How the attack is handled by the Application Servers?

Comment: What research have you done?  There's lots written on HTTP Response Splitting.  You might have better luck asking on Security.SE, but *don't cross-post* - if you want your question moved over there, click "flag" underneath the question to ask the moderators to migrate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, one way to prevent HTTP Response Splitting is for the web framework to make sure it doesn't allow newlines (`\n`) to appear in the headers, not even when the program calls an API to add an extra header to the HTTP response.  Refer to OWASP's materials and other materials on HTTP Response splitting to learn more about how HTTP Response Splitting attacks work and understand why this is a relevant defense.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old attack. It was attacked because of the vulnerability in web server or intermediate proxy. The main cause is parsing of he HTTP message. Nowadays, it is almost fixed   in all modern web servers.